# Codeigniter and Bootstrap slider, how can I loop and load the slides

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to make a bootstrap slider with CodeIgniter, the slider images should be pulled from the database.

each post has a unique slider, so I have 2 database tables, one for the posts and the other for the slides.

the issue is I can't loop through the slides table to pull out the slides that assigned to the post.

I did a join tables between the posts and the slides table so I can get the associated slides, but the result is only loading one slide.

Model:

```
public function get_yachts($slug = FALSE){
      if ($slug === FALSE) {
        $query = $this->db->get('yachts');
        return $query->result_array();
      }
      $this->db->join('yacht_slider', 'yacht_slider.yacht_slide_id = yachts.id');
      $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('slug' => $slug));
      return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function view($slug = NULL){
      $data['yacht'] = $this->yacht_model->get_yachts($slug);
      $data['title'] = 'Yachts';
      $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
      $this->load->view('yachts/view', $data);
      $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
  }
```

In my HTML code, when I try to load the slides like this `<?php echo $yacht['slide'];?>` I only get one row from slides table, so how can I loop to get the rest of the slides. I tried foreach loop and other methods, but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your model `get_yachts` should be like this :*

```
public function get_yachts($slug = FALSE)
{
  if ($slug === FALSE) 
  {
    $query = $this->db->get('yachts');
    return $query->result_array();
  }
  else
  {
    /*$this->db->select('yachts.title as ytitle');*/

    $this->db->join('yacht_slider', 'yacht_slider.yacht_slide_id = yachts.id');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('yachts', array('slug' => $slug));
    return $query->result_array();
  }    
}
```

Controller will remain the same.

*In view access `$yacht` like this:*

*this will work when slug is either empty or not empty*

```
<?php
if (! empty($yacht))
{
    foreach ($yacht as $key => $item) {
        echo $item['slide'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working fine by getting the slides, but now it's only getting the slides, `<?php echo $yacht['title']; ?>` if I use this to echo the title I get an error `Undefined index: title`, and if I use a foreach loop the same way I get the slides, it duplicates the title many times.

Comment: would it be ok if I use the foreach loop like this to get the other database results, `foreach(array_slice($yacht, 0, 1) as $item )` ??

Comment: for that error you have to add the title column with select clause to get the title also with the join , see my updated answer with select in comment

Comment: by the way if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to check it green

Comment: this solution works fine, but I have lots of data to get from the database, I mean I have like 30 columns, so I guess limiting the foreach loop would be better unless you recommend something else.